# How to make a floating widget which isn't destroyed when I change screens?

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a music player and I need the music controls don't reinitialize or disappear on screen changing. If I add the code on another screen it will create another `FloatingControls()` widget.

I've already tried work with keys but that isn't the case because the Widget is recreated when I change screens.

As you can see my `FloatingControls` has a Widget called `YoutubePlayer` when I press play a video starts when I change screens I want that the player doesn't restart.

```
FloatingControls myFloatingControls = FloatingControls(key: Key("myFloatingControls"),);

class MusicSuggestions extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'MusicSuggestions',
      home: new MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Change to Screen A"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            ScreenA(floatingControls: myFloatingControls),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Change to Screen B"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            ScreenB(floatingControls: myFloatingControls),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),

              ],
            ),
            myFloatingControls
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenA extends StatefulWidget {
  final FloatingControls floatingControls;

  const ScreenA({Key key, this.floatingControls}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ScreenAState createState() => _ScreenAState();
}

class _ScreenAState extends State<ScreenA> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: widget.floatingControls,));
  }
}

class ScreenB extends StatefulWidget {
  final FloatingControls floatingControls;

  const ScreenB({Key key, this.floatingControls}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ScreenBState createState() => _ScreenBState();
}

class _ScreenBState extends State<ScreenB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: widget.floatingControls,));
  }
}


class FloatingControls extends StatefulWidget {
  const FloatingControls({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FloatingControlsState createState() => _FloatingControlsState();
}

class _FloatingControlsState extends State<FloatingControls> {
  VideoPlayerController _videoController;
  bool isMute = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipOval(
            child: Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              child: YoutubePlayer(
                autoPlay: false,
                aspectRatio: 1,
                width: 50,
                context: context,
                playerMode: YoutubePlayerMode.NO_CONTROLS,
                source: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PodZolu9v30",
                quality: YoutubeQuality.LOW,
                callbackController: (VideoPlayerController controller) {
                  _videoController = controller;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                  icon: _videoController == null ||
                      !_videoController.value.isPlaying
                      ? Icon(Icons.play_arrow)
                      : Icon(Icons.pause),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _videoController == null ||
                          _videoController.value.isPlaying
                          ? _videoController.pause()
                          : _videoController.play();
                    });
                  }),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              Container(
                width: 25,
                height: 25,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```

I expect to see my `FloatingControls()` in all screens without losing its state when I change pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add floatingControls to your ScreenA and ScreenB build methods.

Example:

```dart
class _ScreenAState extends State<ScreenA> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.floatingControls();
  }
}
```

If you do this for both ScreenA and ScreenB, it should work.

--EDIT--

You should look into the `PageStorage` and `PageStorageBucket` classes, which will help you persist state across rebuilds. I don't have a lot of experience with these, so instead of giving you a potentially shoddy code snippet to copy, I will direct you to [this tutorial by Tensor Programming](https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@tensor/persisting-user-interface-state-and-building-bottom-navigation-bars-in-dart-s-flutter-framework) (whose tutorials have helped me tremendously) which should help you do what you need to do. They are doing it with navigation bars, but it should extend easily to what you're doing.

Comment: I've edited my question. I've changed as you suggests but it didn't work.

Comment: Updated my answer; let me know if that helps!